# Would usort be best for in this scenario of my php script?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I have a working php script that goes through a huge file and pulls out specific movie titles and ratings. But now my assignment is to "sort" them so the movie titles with the 'xxx' are listed at the bottom. I've looked into usort, but with the script I already have written, would that be the best way to go? Or is there a simpler way?

PHP SCRIPT:

```
<?php

foreach (glob("*.mov") as $filename)

$theData = file_get_contents($filename) or die("Unable to retrieve file data");

$months = ['January' => '_01', 'February' =>  '_02', 'March' => '_03', 'April' => '_04', 'May' => '_05', 'June' => '_06', 'July' => '_07', 'August' => '_08', 'September' => '_09', 'October' => '_10', 'November' => '_11', 'December' => '_12'];

foreach($months as $key => $month){
  if(strpos($filename,$month)!==false){
        echo "<div style ='text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #222222; margin-left: 5%; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; font:18px Verdana,tahoma,sans-serif;
                color:#218555; font-weight:bold;'>- Movie List for $key 2013 -</div>";

    }
}


$string = $theData;
$titles = explode("\n", $string);

function getInfo($string){
    $Ratings = ['G', 'PG', 'PG-13', 'R', 'NR', 'XXX'];
    $split = preg_split("/\"(.+)\"/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE); 
    if(count($split) == 3){ 
        preg_match("/(".implode("|", $Ratings).")\s/", $split[0], $matches);
        $rating = $matches[0];
        return ["title" => $split[1], "rating" => $rating];
    }
    return false;
}

foreach($titles as $title){
    $info = getInfo($title);
    if($info !== false){
        echo "<div style ='margin-left:5%; margin-bottom: 3px; 
                font:14px Verdana,tahoma,sans-serif;color:green;'>
                 {$info["title"]} : {$info["rating"]}</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

OUTPUTS:

```
- Movie List for May 2013 -
(HD) Identity Thief : PG-13
(HD) Escape from Planet Earth : PG
(HD) Dark Skies : PG-13
(HD) The Guilt Trip : PG-13
(HD) Jack Reacher : PG-13
(HD) Les Miserables : PG-13
(HD) Mama : PG-13
(HD) Safe Haven : PG-13
(HD) A Place at the Table : PG
(HD) Cirque du Soleil: Worlds Away : PG
(HD) Rise of the Guardians : PG
(HD) Fun Size : PG-13
(HD) Shanghai Calling : PG-13
(HD) The Package : NR
(HD) The House at the End of the Street : PG-13
Beautiful Creatures : PG-13
The Incredible Burt Wonderstone : PG-13
Jack the Giant Slayer : PG-13
Parental Guidance : PG
The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey : PG-13
Cloud Atlas : PG-13
Life of Pi : PG
Chasing Mavericks : PG
Taken 2 : PG-13
Adult title 1 : XXX
Fat Burning Hip Hop Dance Party : G
Fat Burning Hip Hop Dance Grooves : G
Aladdin : G
Americano : NR
Missing Brendan : NR
Point Doom : NR
Gullivers Travels : G
The Little Princess : PG
Jack And The Beanstalk : PG
To the Arctic : G
Adult title 2 : XXX
```

Need to get the titles with XXX to sort to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you first build up a list of the info details like this:

```
$infolist = array();
foreach($titles as $title){
    $info = getInfo($title);
    if($info !== false){
        $infolist[] = $info;
    }
}
```

Then you can easily sort that list with `usort` since the rating is now easily accessible:

```
usort($infolist, "infosort");

function infosort($lhs,$rhs) {
  return strcmp($lhs['rating'], $rhs['rating']);
}
```

And finally you can write out the sorted results from the infolist array:

```
foreach ($infolist as $info) {
  echo "<div style ='margin-left:5%; margin-bottom: 3px;
          font:14px Verdana,tahoma,sans-serif;color:green;'> 
           {$info["title"]} : {$info["rating"]}</div>";
}
```

Comment: it echo's correctly after giving me tons of ':' before it goes through the function. Is there a way to NOT show the ':' for any data that is not getting parsed. In other words, I get 45 separate lines with a colon, and then I get the data I actually want in an ordered way.

Comment: I probably should have included a check for false after the `getInfo` call. Will update the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: OH yeah, i just added that before the infolist[]...     if($info !== false){
THANK YOU SO MUCH @ James Holderness